# Is there a command in python that allows you to re-execute the function that was just executed?

Tags: python

I am coding a general maths equation calculator, that calculates the area/perimeter of 2D shapes, surface area/volume of 3D shapes, and any formulas that I will decide to build in the future.

I am trying to build a function that will let the user decide whether they want to use the equation that was already used again.

It would be inefficient if I created a function with the same purpose in every section of the program(which I already tried).

```
def triangledecision():
    print("Input 1 if you would like to calculate the area/perimeter of this shape again")
    print("Input 2 if you would like to return to the 2D shape menu")
    print("Input 3 if you would like to return to the main menu")
    answer = input()

    if answer == "1":
        triangle()

    if answer == "2":
        twodshapes()

    if answer == "3":
        main()

    else:
        while answer != "1" or "2" or "3":
            print("Please select one of the options")
            triangledecision()
```

This function works as intended, however, I would have to create the same function for every single section which would be time-consuming and inefficient.

Comment: Why don't you create the function only once, and call it as many times as needed inside a loop?

Comment: What's the problem with just recalling the same function multiple times?

Comment: Nothing wrong with recalling the same function over and over again, what I am trying to say is that I need to create a function that can execute the function that has been executed, again. For example, if I just calculated the area of a circle, I want to ask the user whether they want to calculate the area of another circle, if not go back to the main menu... If they calculated the area of a square, ask if they want to calculate the area of another square... And rather than me creating the same function over and over again; create a function that executes the function that was just executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like a decorator to achieve this. I'm a bit confused what your asking, but I am assuming you would like a generic function that can work on all your operations. I would create a retry wrapper.

```py
def retry(func):
   def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
      while True:
         func(*args, **kwargs)
         answer = input('if would you like to calculate the area or perimeter of this shape again, enter 1: ')
         if answer != '1':
            break
      return 
   return wrapper
```

Then you use `@retry` over your functions. Ex:

```py
@retry
def square_perimeter():
   #whatever your code is
```

Using this you can ask the user to reuse any function by simply decorating it with the `@retry` decorator.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I meant. A generic function that I can use in any function to ask the user whether they want to use the same piece of code again(e.g do you want to calculate the area/perimeter of this shape again?) Thanks for your reply.

Comment: No problem, if this solved you problem you can accept my answer by clicking the checkmark beside it.

Answer (score 0):

In python you can save functions as variables (more intuitively, they are objects). As follows:
`executedFunction = triangle`
or
`executedFunction = twoshapes`
and then call it:
`executedFunction()`